# Geocode API returning zero results for valid lat/lng

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

Google reverse geocode api returning zero result when using lat/lng but returns correct result using place_id
For example
Calling below link(replace key with your API key) returns the result
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJhe1fRCHr_TgREPeGUJcJu9E&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

But calling below link for same location using lat/lng returns zero result
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.1525864,77.57705349999999

Comment: You'll get ZERO_RESULTS for any area in J&K India

Comment: Then why would I would I get some result in an area in J&K when I search by place_id?

Answer (score 0):

The LatLng is placed in a disputed area, google usually tries to avoid to include results from such places.

Comment: If this is a disputed area then why would google return result when searching by place_id instead of lat/lng?

Comment: maybe because they've decided to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SnappyGuide Reverse Geocoding API](http://snappyguide.com/doc/places/geocode) if you are open to use any other service other than google?  Ref: http://api.snappyguide.com:8087/user/places/geocode?location=34.1525864,77.57705349999999